# ojdbc upgrade oci connection url not longer working

Tags: java, ojdbc

I am upgrading ojdbc jar from ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar to ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar. With ojdbc6 the used connection url was like jdbc:oracle:oci:@ORACLE and it seems the connection works, however with ojdbc8 that same url no longer works. Do i need to use thin or i am using the wrong ojdbc8 jar?

[edit]
java 1.8.201 32 bit
stack trace not available
oracle 12.2

Comment: What is your Java version? Please add the error message and stack trace that you get on failed connection.

Comment: Be careful with oracle, old oracle databases (e.g. 9i) don't work with newer ojdbc